# Need different default keyboard settings for different users

Tags: keyboard, gui, user, settings

I set up Raspberry Pi 4 workstations with Raspbian Buster for a school library and want to use a different keyboard setting for the `root` account.

Now it seems to me that I can only change the settings for the whole system and non-`root` accounts cannot change the settings at all.

As it runs LightDM, I guess I could run a script that changes the keyboard settings but IMHO there has to be a way for `non-roots` to change the settings for their accounts.

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask this question on another SE site. I suggest [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions).

Comment: Raspbian doesn't have a `root` account! The `pi` user has `sudo` privileges and other users have whatever privileges they are granted on creation.

Comment: **Raspbian has a root account.**  Whether you want to use it directly or pi `sudo` is up to you, the risks are essentially the same.  In fact, *the pi user having such powers is an attack vector*, ie., de-fanging the pi user and  using the root account directly would be better security wise.  The default setup is intended to make life easier for new users, not protect anyone from anything.  In a school I would presume a regular user is does not have all superpowers, and pi is either de-fanged or superfluous.

Comment: WRT to the actual question, here's one option/clue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258874/different-languages-keyboard-layouts-for-different-users-debian More: https://askubuntu.com/questions/155861/how-do-i-change-keyboard-layout-for-just-one-user-on-ubuntu-server I suspect you are using "raspberry pi" in your search terms rather than "linux",  which is more useful.